# How to check if a Memo is populated in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I am adding error messages to a `Memo` when the user makes incorrect entries on a form. So if there are no error messages, there are no entries in the `Memo`.  I want the `Memo` to become visible and display the error messages (if there are any) when a `Save` button is pressed.  If there aren't any error messages, then I want the form to be able to close upon pressing the `Save` button.  The following code works with `try finally end` but not with `try except end`, meaning that with the `except`, it seems to skip the `except` block and does not close the form even if there are no error messages and the `Memo` is clear.  The following code works exactly as i want it to.  Sorry about posting the code for the entire procedure, but I wonder why `try except end` does not allow the form to close.

```
procedure TfrmAnalysisOptions.btnSaveOptionsClick(Sender: TObject);
//save input and output options
var
  I: integer;
  Chr: char;
  Temp, Val: string;
  const Allowed = ['0'..'9', '.'];
  const AllowedPlus = ['0'..'9', '.', '-'];
begin
  ErrorMsgMemo.Clear;
  ErrorMsgMemo.Visible := True;
  //Populate memo with error messages if user makes mistakes
  try
    if (rgConstraintMinMax.ItemIndex = -1) then //if no radiobutton checked
      begin
    ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Do you want to constrain the minimum ' +
                   'and maximum input response variables?  ' +
                   'Please choose Yes or No.');
      end;
    if (rgConstraintMinMax.ItemIndex = 0) then //if Yes chosen
      begin
    ConstraintsYesNo := 'Yes';
      end;
    //error checking if user chooses to enter constraint values
    if (rgConstraintMinMax.ItemIndex = 1) then //if No chosen
      begin
    //is min constraint value valid?
    if ((lbleConstraintsMin.Enabled = True) and
          (lbleConstraintsMin.Text = '')) then
      begin
        ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Please enter value for minimum ' +
                   'input response value constraint.');
      end;
    //is min constraint value valid? - contd.
    Temp := lbleConstraintsMin.Text;
    for I := 1 to Length(Temp) do
      begin
        Chr := Temp[I];
        if not (Chr in Allowed) then
          begin
        ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Minimum constraint value ' +
                       'invalid.');
        Exit;
          end;
      end;
    if ((lbleConstraintsMin.Text = '') or
        (lbleConstraintsMin.Text = '-') or
        (lbleConstraintsMin.Text = '.') or
        (lbleConstraintsMin.Text = '.0') or
        (lbleConstraintsMin.Text = '-.') or
        (lbleConstraintsMin.Text = '-.0') or
        (lbleConstraintsMin.Text = '-0') or
        (lbleConstraintsMin.Text = '0.') or
        (lbleConstraintsMin.Text = '-0.')) then
      begin
        ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Please enter or correct the ' +
                   'minimum constraint value');
      end;
    //is max constraint value valid?
    if ((lbleConstraintsMax.Enabled = True) and
          (lbleConstraintsMax.Text = '')) then
      begin
        ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Please enter value for maximum ' +
                   'input response value constraint.');
      end;
    //is max constraint value valid? - contd.
    Temp := lbleConstraintsMax.Text;
    for I := 1 to Length(Temp) do
      begin
        Chr := Temp[I];
        if not (Chr in Allowed) then
          begin
        ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Maximum constraint value ' +
                       'invalid.');
        Exit;
          end;
      end;
    //is max constraint value valid? - contd.
    if ((lbleConstraintsMax.Text = '') or
        (lbleConstraintsMax.Text = '-') or
        (lbleConstraintsMax.Text = '.') or
        (lbleConstraintsMax.Text = '.0') or
        (lbleConstraintsMax.Text = '-.') or
        (lbleConstraintsMax.Text = '-.0') or
        (lbleConstraintsMax.Text = '-0') or
        (lbleConstraintsMax.Text = '0.') or
        (lbleConstraintsMax.Text = '-0.')) then
      begin
        ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Please enter or correct the ' +
                   'maximum constraint value');
      end;
    //now for more error-checking for both constraints
    if not ((TryStrToFloat(lbleConstraintsMin.Text,
             InputConstraintMinValue)) and
        (TryStrToFloat(lbleConstraintsMax.Text,
             InputConstraintMaxValue))) then Exit;
    //max constraint cannot be zero or less than min constraint
    if ((InputConstraintMaxValue = 0) or
        (InputConstraintMaxValue < 0) or
        (InputConstraintMaxValue < InputConstraintMinValue) or
        (InputConstraintMinValue = InputConstraintMaxValue)) then
      begin
        ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Max constraint value cannot be ' +
                   'negative, zero, or equal to or less ' +
                   'than Min value.');
      end;
      end;

    //check the EC50 iteration range for errors
    if (rgRespIterRangeFromData.ItemIndex = -1) then//if no rb chosen
    begin
      ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Do you want to iterate over the range ' +
                 'of the values of the dose variable in the ' +
                 'data? Please choose Yes or No.');
    end;
    if (rgRespIterRangeFromData.ItemIndex = 0) then //if Yes is chosen
      begin
    EC50RangeFromData := 'Yes';
      end;
    //check for errors if user chooses to enter EC50 iteration range values
    if (rgRespIterRangeFromData.ItemIndex = 1) then //if No is chosen
      begin
    EC50RangeFromData := 'No';
    //is min value for EC50 iteration range valid?
    if ((lblePercentRespMinValue.Enabled = True) and
           (lblePercentRespMinValue.Text = '')) then
      begin
        ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Please enter minimum iteration ' +
                 'range value for EC50 estimation.');
      end;
    //is min value for EC50 iteration range valid? - contd.
    Temp := lblePercentRespMinValue.Text;
    for I := 1 to Length(Temp) do
      begin
        Chr := Temp[I];
        if not (Chr in Allowed) then
          begin
        ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Minimum iteration range value ' +
                       'for EC50 invalid.');
        Exit;
          end;
      end;
    if ((lblePercentRespMinValue.Text = '-') or
        (lblePercentRespMinValue.Text = '.') or
        (lblePercentRespMinValue.Text = '.0') or
        (lblePercentRespMinValue.Text = '-.') or
        (lblePercentRespMinValue.Text = '-.0') or
        (lblePercentRespMinValue.Text = '-0') or
        (lblePercentRespMinValue.Text = '0.') or
        (lblePercentRespMinValue.Text = '-0.')) then
      begin
        ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Please enter or correct the ' +
                   'minimum value for the EC50 iteration ' +
                   'range.');
      end;
    //is max value for EC50 iteration range valid?
    if ((lblePercentRespMaxValue.Enabled = True) and
           (lblePercentRespMaxValue.Text = '')) then
    begin
      ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Please enter maximum iteration ' +
                 'range value for EC50 estimation.');
    end;
    //is max value for EC50 iteration range valid? - contd.
    Temp := lblePercentRespMaxValue.Text;
    for I := 1 to Length(Temp) do
      begin
        Chr := Temp[I];
        if not (Chr in Allowed) then
          begin
        ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Maximum iteration range value ' +
                       'for EC50 invalid.');
        Exit;
          end;
      end;
    if ((lblePercentRespMaxValue.Text = '-') or
        (lblePercentRespMaxValue.Text = '.') or
        (lblePercentRespMaxValue.Text = '.0') or
        (lblePercentRespMaxValue.Text = '-.') or
        (lblePercentRespMaxValue.Text = '-.0') or
        (lblePercentRespMaxValue.Text = '-0') or
        (lblePercentRespMaxValue.Text = '0.') or
        (lblePercentRespMaxValue.Text = '-0.')) then
      begin
        ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Please enter or correct the ' +
                   'Maximum value for the EC50 iteration ' +
                   'range.');
      end;
    //now for more error checking for both EC50 range values
    if not ((TryStrToFloat(lblePercentRespMinValue.Text,
                IterationRangeMinValue)) and
        (TryStrToFloat(lblePercentRespMaxValue.Text,
                IterationRangeMaxValue))) then Exit;
    //max Ec50 range value cannot be 0, negative or <= min value
    if ((IterationRangeMaxValue = 0) or
        (IterationRangeMaxValue < 0) or
        (IterationRangeMaxValue < IterationRangeMinValue) or
        (IterationRangeMaxValue = IterationRangeMinValue)) then
      begin
        ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Max EC50 iteration range value ' +
                   'cannot be negative, zero or equal to or' +
                   'less than the Min value.');
      end;
      end;


    //check the HillSlope iteration range for errors
    if (lbleHillslopeMinValue.Text = '') then
      begin
    ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Please enter minimum iteration range ' +
                   'value for Hill slope coefficient.');
      end;
    if (lbleHillslopeMaxValue.Text = '') then
      begin
    ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Please enter maximum iteration range ' +
                   'value for Hill slope coefficient.');
      end;
    //get HillSlope iteration range values - along with error checking
    if ((lbleHillslopeMinValue.Text <> '') and
       (lbleHillslopeMaxValue.Text <> '')) then
      begin
    Temp := lbleHillslopeMinValue.Text;
    for I := 1 to Length(Temp) do
      begin
        Chr := Temp[I];
        if not (Chr in AllowedPlus) then
          begin
        ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Minimum iteration range value ' +
                       'for HillSlope invalid.');
        Exit;
          end;
      end;
    if ((lbleHillslopeMinValue.Text = '-') or
        (lbleHillslopeMinValue.Text = '.') or
        (lbleHillslopeMinValue.Text = '.0') or
        (lbleHillslopeMinValue.Text = '-.') or
        (lbleHillslopeMinValue.Text = '-.0') or
        (lbleHillslopeMinValue.Text = '-0') or
        (lbleHillslopeMinValue.Text = '0.') or
        (lbleHillslopeMinValue.Text = '-0.')) then
      begin
        ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Please enter or correct the ' +
                   'Minimum value for the HillSlope ' +
                   'iteration range.');
      end;
    Temp := lbleHillslopeMaxValue.Text;
    for I := 1 to Length(Temp) do
      begin
        Chr := Temp[I];
        if not (Chr in AllowedPlus) then
          begin
        ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Maximum iteration range value ' +
                       'for HillSlope invalid.');
        Exit;
          end;
      end;
    if ((lbleHillslopeMaxValue.Text = '-') or
        (lbleHillslopeMaxValue.Text = '.') or
        (lbleHillslopeMaxValue.Text = '.0') or
        (lbleHillslopeMaxValue.Text = '-.') or
        (lbleHillslopeMaxValue.Text = '-.0') or
        (lbleHillslopeMaxValue.Text = '-0') or
        (lbleHillslopeMaxValue.Text = '0.') or
        (lbleHillslopeMaxValue.Text = '-0.')) then
      begin
        ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Please enter or correct the ' +
                   'maximum value for the HillSlope ' +
                   'iteration range.');
      end;
    if not ((TryStrToFloat(lbleHillslopeMinValue.Text,
                IterationRangeHSMinValue)) and
           (TryStrToFloat(lbleHillslopeMaxValue.Text,
                IterationRangeHSMaxValue))) then Exit;
    //max constraint cannot be zero or less than min constraint
    if ((IterationRangeHSMaxValue = 0) or
        (IterationRangeHSMaxValue <
          IterationRangeHSMinValue)) then
      begin
        ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Max value for HillSlope iteration' +
                   'cannot be zero or less than Min value.');
      end;
      end;

  //get confidence and prediction band levels (with error checks)
    if (cbCILimits.Text = '') then
    begin
      ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Please select the % level for the ' +
                 'confidence band.');
    end;
    if (cbCILimits.Text <> '') then
    begin
      if not (TryStrToFloat(cbCILimits.Text, CIPercent)) then Exit;
    end;
    if (cbPILimits.Text = '') then
    begin
      ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Please select the % level for the ' +
                 'prediction band.');
    end;
    if (cbPILimits.Text <> '') then
    begin
      if not (TryStrToFloat(cbPILimits.Text, PIPercent)) then Exit;
    end;

    //get F table values for Conf and Pred bands with error checking
    if (lbleFValue.Text = '') then
    begin
      ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Please enter the F value from ' +
                 'statistical tables.');
    end;
    if (lbleFValue.Text <> '') then
    begin
      Temp := lbleFValue.Text;
      for I := 1 to Length(Temp) do
    begin
      Chr := Temp[I];
      if not (Chr in Allowed) then
        begin
          ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: F value invalid.');
          Exit;
        end;
    end;
      if ((lbleFValue.Text = '-') or
      (lbleFValue.Text = '.') or
      (lbleFValue.Text = '.0') or
      (lbleFValue.Text = '-.') or
      (lbleFValue.Text = '-.0') or
      (lbleFValue.Text = '-0') or
      (lbleFValue.Text = '0.') or
      (lbleFValue.Text = '-0.')) then
    begin
      ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Please enter or correct the F value.');
    end;
      if not (TryStrToFloat(lbleFValue.Text, FValue)) then Exit;
    end;

    //get t table values for Conf and Pred bands with error checking
    if (lbletValue.Text = '') then
    begin
      ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Please enter the (two-tailed) t value ' +
                 'from statistical tables.');
    end;
    if (lbletValue.Text <> '') then
    begin
      Temp := lbletValue.Text;
      for I := 1 to Length(Temp) do
    begin
      Chr := Temp[I];
      if not (Chr in Allowed) then
        begin
          ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: t value invalid.');
          Exit;
        end;
    end;
      if ((lbletValue.Text = '-') or
      (lbletValue.Text = '.') or
      (lbletValue.Text = '.0') or
      (lbletValue.Text = '-.') or
      (lbletValue.Text = '-.0') or
      (lbletValue.Text = '-0') or
      (lbletValue.Text = '0.') or
      (lbletValue.Text = '-0.')) then
    begin
      ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Add('ERROR: Please enter or correct the t value.');
    end;
      if not (TryStrToFloat(lbletValue.Text, tValue)) then Exit;
    end;
  //if no error messages, then save all option values and close form
  finally
    if (ErrorMsgMemo.Lines.Count = 0) then
      begin
    FormSaved := 'Form Saved';//has options form been saved?
    Close;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You seem to be using visual controls (TMemo) to store non-visual information (counter and list of errors). That is generally an anti-pattern and you'd truly better separate data from its representation (see MVC pattern and its derivatives). One day you would want to change how you alert for errors or to log them into e-mail or whatever - and would be almost unable to do it, because once chosen TMemo as counter and container. I suggest you installing JediVCL (http://jvcl.sf.net) and run Validators demo to see different visual modes that you can use if separated data storage from GUI/VCL)

Comment: Sorry, @Arioch, I just noticed your comment. I want to alert the user to the errors when they try to save their input options. As to your suggestion, I'm afraid I am too much of a novice to understand it fully.  Thanks, though.

Comment: That is never late to learn. And if you are novice - then i especially repeat my suggestion. install JediCodeLib and JediVCL, then run JvValidators demo. There are very different styles how to  make users alert, and you better have the taste in your mouth, before you would stick your program with a single most eay to develop but most hard to use option.

Comment: Now, about MVC... I would just tell you a story. There was a Jabber client named JAJC. It was very cool and slick and i liked it a lot. It arguably was the best of the breed. But time went, jabber protocol was extending, other clients were catching up, and JAJC client had to extend itself. Then one day its developer said "i can no more develop the client - it turned to be unmaintainable mess, it is just a spaghetti code without any structure". Community asked "then make it open-source, perhaps someone will rework it and give it new life". And he said "i wish to but cannot"

Comment: He started with the same Delphi narcotic that you are going to get addicted - storing data inside visual controls. It was too easy to draft it that way. Then he found TMemo is not looking good enough and he purchased commercial components. Then he remade those components adding them more features to store the different data he could need. Then one day he found that he can not rework his code - because there were no more program structure: there was only forms and components structure. Ans spaghetti of program. And since he used custom derived controls, he could not say "you need to buy

Comment: Library XXX and YYY to compile JAJC" And since he derived them from commercial components he could not open-source it. And since he chosen comfort of using visual components instead of separating logic from GUI, he could not rework the program. JAJC was dead, cold dead.

Using TMemo to keep your data is a first step to become addict. It would give  you a head start. But remember - in a year from today you better drop your program and never touch it again. If that is okay - then go on, coding "fast and ugly". If your program is to live seriously, then refrain yourself from this doping drug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Lines.Count` property:

```
if (ErrorMemo.Lines.Count > 0) then
```

Or the `GetTextLen()` method:

```
if (ErrorMemo.GetTextLen() > 0) then
```

Or simply keep track of whether you add an error to the Memo:

```
procedure btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  //
  HasError: Boolean;
begin
  ErrorMemo.Clear;
  ErrorMemo.Visible := True;
  HasError := False;
  try
    ...
    if (something is errored) then
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(...);
      HasError := True;
    end;
    ...
  except
    if (not HasError) then Close;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, @Remy.  I am voting for this answer since there were other options as well.

Comment: Actually, only just now had a chance to check out these options. The options given by @Remy seemed so reasonable that I voted for his response.  However, very interestingly, none of the suggestions worked when I used a `try except end` block but suggestions 1 and 3 of @Remy worked when I used a `try finally end` block. Suggestion 2 did (`GetTextLen()`) not work with either block.  Any idea why?

Comment: @user1505202: Without seeing the actual code you used, it is hard to say why something did not work. None of the suggestions I gave you are subject to differences between `try/finally` and `try/except`.  The real question is, why are you using `try/except` in the first place? It sounds like maybe you are raising an exception before you added anything to the Memo. That would account for none of the suggestions working. However, if that were the case, then a `try/finally` should not have worked, either. So please show the actual code you are using.

Comment: Your loops have `Exit` statements after adding text to the Memo. That would not call code that is in an `except` block, but would call code that is in a `finally` block. I think you meant to use `Break` instead of `Exit`.

Answer (score 3):

Memo.Lines is a TStrings, so you add to it by

`Memo.Lines.Add(string)`

and check for no lines (empty) of lines by

`Memo.Lines.Count = 0`